# Angular 2 NFor loop not displaying

Tags: json, angular

I don't get any errors to go off and the JSON is returned from the backend fine.
Question is, have I done anything wrong in the code below?

JSON

```
{
    "Data": [{
        "ProfileId": "121212",
        "Name": "Charles",
        "info": {
            "rating": "0",
            "plot": "Nothing happens at all."
        }
    }]
}
```

Home.Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from "@angular/core";
import { HomeService } from './home.service';
import { Profile } from './profile';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "home-page",
    templateUrl: "home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["home.component.css"],
    providers:  [ HomeService ]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private service: HomeService) {}

    Profiles: Profile[];

    getProfile(): void {
        this.service
            .getData()
            .then(profiles => this.Profiles = profiles);

    }
    ngOnInit(){
        this.getProfile();
    }

}
```

Home.service.ts

```
import {Injectable  } from "@angular/core";
import {Headers, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Profile } from './profile';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
    private usersUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/';
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getData(): Promise<Profile[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.usersUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Profile[])
            .catch(this.handleError);

        //let err = new Error('Cannot get object of this type');

    }


    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

home.component.html

```html
<h2>HOME</h2>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let prof of Profiles;">
        {{prof.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Rendered as this in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh287.png)

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @MChaker, sorry was just adding it via edit. Is there anything obvious in the code I posted that would be causing it to not work?

Answer (score 1):

```
{{prof.name}}
```

should be

```
{{prof.Name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your picture gives a hint of the array being `null` with:

```
...ng-for-of: null
```

so besides the mention by Günther of that `{{prof.name}}` should be `{{prof.Name}}`, 
your JSON holds `Data`, (with capital letter), but in your get-request you are using `data`. This is actually case sensitive, so the following line

```
.then(response => response.json().data as Profile[])
```

should be:

```
.then(response => response.json().Data as Profile[])
```

that should populate your array correctly :)